# Display of Powershell5

Tags: powershell, fonts, visual-studio-code, powershell-5.0

Q: how to change my `powershell` back into normal? (not for legacy mode)

Discription: `powershell` always open in wrong display mode, and the solution I've searched on web not work.

As shown, I can not change the font type and size after restart `powershell`, and I've tried to change registry:  `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` to change, but not work.
However the `cmd` and `wsl` (or bash) is working right. And the `powershell-ise` is also right.

Meanwhile, I found my `vscode-terminal` can not display the prefix of `powershell`, unless I change the console into legacy mode. But if I change the legacy mode, the `powershell` still can not try other font type and size, which is tough to read.

#### Console

[image: shell]

#### ISE

[image: shell-ise]

#### WSL

[image: bash]

#### VSCode

[image: vscode]

#### Comparison

[image: compare]

Comment: Hello and welcome! I've edited your question a bit to embed the images, but I'm thinking this question really belongs on [su] rather than Stack Overflow (they are sister sites, part of the same network). That site is specialized toward these types of questions, so I will recommend that you post there, and then close this question here.

Comment: Try starting the ps console as Administrator and do the font and size settings. Close the console and restart normal. Do the changes stick then?

Comment: The question remain unsolved, and according to the advice, I've moved it into [Super User-Powershell Display](https://superuser.com/questions/1389230/powershell-display-error) here.

Comment: NEWEST found, even if I switch to admin account to change all settings, it doesn't work. Fun thing is, if I open powershell right here `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`, all things goes well. But if I create a shortcut, It can not change fonts.(nothing with shortcut settings, I tried but no use).